# Best way to store timestamp and date in google datastore with java 8

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

What is the best way to save a `long` timestamp in milliseconds to a field in Google Datastore in Java 8?
Also, what would be a good way to save a human readable date using those same milliseconds?

I am using these and setting them as a property in an entity:

```
long milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
Date date = new Date();
```

But I read that `Date` is deprecated? When I save the `date` variable as above into Datastore and look at it in the Console sometimes it shows as `August 10, 2022 at 6:22:32 PM UTC-4` or `August 10, 2022 at 6:22:32 PM UTC-5` (with the UTC-4 or UTC-5. I am not sure why they are sometimes different).

I have also seen these different ways but I am not sure which is the best/recommended when working on the Google Cloud to have things nice and standardized.:

```
Timestamp timestamp = new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());
long currentTimeJava8 = Instant.now().toEpochMilli();
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
long milliSeconds = Timestamp.valueOf(now).getTime();
```